# How do I validate XML document using RELAX NG schema in C# wiht validator Nu of the w3c?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, w3c, relaxng

This is the error I found in my code:

```
Invalid datatype was found for namespace 'http://whattf.org/datatype-draft' and local name 'string'.
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
    RelaxngPattern g = Compile("C:\\nu\\validator-master\\validator-master\\schema\\html5\\xhtml5.rnc");

                        XmlTextReader xml_memori = new XmlTextReader(memStream);
                        RelaxngValidatingReader r= new RelaxngValidatingReader(xml_memori,g);
                        try
                        {
                            while (!r.EOF)
                                r.Read();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            r.Close();
                        }


 RelaxngPattern Compile(string file)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                return Compile(sr, file);
            }
        }

        RelaxngPattern Compile(TextReader reader)
        {
            return Compile(reader, null);
        }

        RelaxngPattern Compile(TextReader reader, string baseUri)
        {
            RncParser parser = new RncParser(new NameTable());
            RelaxngPattern g = parser.Parse(reader, baseUri);
            g.Compile();
            return g;
        }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you might be interested in the [unsoup/validator](https://github.com/unsoup/validator) GitHub repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate xml document against relaxNG schema in libxml++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024396/how-to-validate-xml-document-against-relaxng-schema-in-libxml)